# Query times out in .Net SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery, works in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, timeout, ssms

**Update: Problem solved, and staying solved.** *If you want to see the site in action, visit [Tweet08](http://www.tweet08.com)*

I've got several queries that act differently in SSMS versus when run inside my .Net application.  The SSMS executes fine in under a second.  The .Net call times out after 120 seconds (connection default timeout).

I did a SQL Trace (and collected *everything*) I've seen that the connection options are the same (and match the SQL Server's defaults). The SHOWPLAN All, however, show a huge difference in the row estimates and thus the working version does an aggressive Table Spool, where-as the failing call does not.

In the SSMS, the datatypes of the temp variables are based on the generated SQL Parameters in the .Net, so they are the same.

The failure executes under Cassini in a VS2008 debug session. The success is under SSMS 2008 . Both are running against the same destination server form the same network on the same machine.

Query in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @ContentTableID0 TINYINT
DECLARE @EntryTag1 INT
DECLARE @ContentTableID2 TINYINT
DECLARE @FieldCheckId3 INT
DECLARE @FieldCheckValue3 VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @FieldCheckId5 INT
DECLARE @FieldCheckValue5 VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @FieldCheckId7 INT 
DECLARE @FieldCheckValue7 VARCHAR(128)
SET @ContentTableID0= 3
SET @EntryTag1= 8
SET @ContentTableID2= 2
SET @FieldCheckId3= 14
SET @FieldCheckValue3= 'igor'
SET @FieldCheckId5= 33
SET @FieldCheckValue5= 'a'
SET @FieldCheckId7= 34
SET @FieldCheckValue7= 'a'

SELECT COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM dbo.ContentEntry AS mainCE
WHERE GetUTCDate() BETWEEN mainCE.CreatedOn AND mainCE.ExpiredOn
AND (mainCE.ContentTableID=@ContentTableID0)
AND ( EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM dbo.ContentEntryLabel
              WHERE ContentEntryID = mainCE.ID
              AND GetUTCDate() BETWEEN CreatedOn AND ExpiredOn
              AND LabelFacetID = @EntryTag1))
      AND (mainCE.OwnerGUID IN (SELECT TOP 1 Name
                                FROM dbo.ContentEntry AS innerCE1
                                WHERE GetUTCDate() BETWEEN innerCE1.CreatedOn AND innerCE1.ExpiredOn
                                AND (innerCE1.ContentTableID=@ContentTableID2
                                     AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                 FROM dbo.ContentEntryField
                                                 WHERE ContentEntryID = innerCE1.ID
                                                 AND (ContentTableFieldID = @FieldCheckId3
                                                      AND DictionaryValueID IN (SELECT dv.ID
                                                                                FROM dbo.DictionaryValue AS dv
                                                                                WHERE dv.Word LIKE '%' + @FieldCheckValue3 + '%'))
                                                )
                                    )
                               )
           OR EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM dbo.ContentEntryField
                      WHERE ContentEntryID = mainCE.ID
                      AND (   (ContentTableFieldID = @FieldCheckId5
                               AND DictionaryValueID IN (SELECT dv.ID
                                                         FROM dbo.DictionaryValue AS dv
                                                         WHERE dv.Word LIKE '%' + @FieldCheckValue5 + '%')
                              )
                           OR (ContentTableFieldID = @FieldCheckId7
                               AND DictionaryValueID IN (SELECT dv.ID
                                                         FROM dbo.DictionaryValue AS dv
                                                         WHERE dv.Word LIKE '%' + @FieldCheckValue7 + '%')
                               )
                          )
                     )
          )
```

Trace's version of .Net call (*some formatting added*):

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) ...'
,N'@ContentTableID0 tinyint
,@EntryTag1 int
,@ContentTableID2 tinyint
,@FieldCheckId3 int
,@FieldCheckValue3 varchar(128)
,@FieldCheckId5 int
,@FieldCheckValue5 varchar(128)
,@FieldCheckId7 int
,@FieldCheckValue7 varchar(128)'
,@ContentTableID0=3
,@EntryTag1=8
,@ContentTableID2=2
,@FieldCheckId3=14
,@FieldCheckValue3='igor'
,@FieldCheckId5=33
,@FieldCheckValue5='a'
,@FieldCheckId7=34
,@FieldCheckValue7='a'
```

Comment: SQL Server Standard 2005, not the only query this happens to, but quite representative and reproducible.

Comment: Post the client-side code that calls this.

Comment: And are you sure they're the same?  if you call .AddWithValue() .Net will create an NVarChar parameter rather than a VarChar and won't be able to use any VarChar indexes.

Comment: In SSMS, when it works, the statement causes 86214 logical reads. In .Net land, when it times out, it causes 746033 logical reads (due to the missing Table Spool).

Comment: Yes, absolutely sure. Our query-building code in .Net _knows_ the column types and emits the correct SqlParameter types to ensure indexes don't get discarded.

Comment: I am sorry, if I sound like an idiot. Do both example point to same server/db?

Comment: Good question. Yes, same destination server, same network, same machine (e.g. Cassini/Asp.Net for the failure, SSMS 2008 for the success).

Comment: I just noticed this, What is the "codegen" that you refer to?  Is that what is changing it into the sp_executesql calls and parametrizing it?

Comment: I'm using "codegen" as a short-hand for our SqlParameter-creating code  which is synched to the actual datatypes in the database. We _always_ generate the correct SqlType values.

As a closing comment, since the server was rebooted, this issue has not arised again... joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked and this server, a development server, was not running SQL Server 2005 SP3. Tried to install that (with necessary reboot), but it didn't install. Oddly now both code and SSMS return in subsecond time.

Woot this is a HEISENBUG.

Comment: That's just because you flushed the query plan cache.  It will come back unless you fix it.

Comment: I agree that it _should be_ because of that. However it never came back. I suspect one of the Windows Updates that installed at reboot had some effect. That or something in the Hyper-V host got happy.

Answer (score 4):

It is not your indexes.

This is parameter-sniffing, as it usually happens to parametrized stored procedures.  It is not widely known, even among those who know about parameter-sniffing, but it can also happen when you use parameters through sp_executesql.

You will note that the version that you are testing in SSMS and the version the the profiler is showing are not identical because the profiler version shows that your .Net application is executing it through sp_executesql.  If you extract and execute the full sql text that is actually being run for your application, then I believe that you will see the same performance problem with the same query plan.

FYI: the query plans being different is the key indicator of parameter-sniffing.

FIX: The easiest way to fix this one assuming it is executing on SQL Server 2005 or 2008 is to add the clause "OPTION (RECOMPILE)" as the last line of you SELECT statement.  Be forewarned, you may have to execute it twice before it works and it does not always work on SQL Server 2005.  If that happens, then there are other steps that you can take, but they are a little bit more involved.

One thing that you could try is to check and see if "Forced Parameterization" has been turned on for your database (it should be in the SSMS Database properties, under the Options page).  To tunr Forced Parameterization off execute this command:

```
    ALTER DATABASE [yourDB] SET  PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE
```

Comment: You are correct about the sp_executesql I would be surprised if that's the cause as this is ONLY statement against the server that could match the plan cache (fresh restart). 

I can't force a recompile on every statement my codegen makes, that would hammer the server.

Can I disable parameterization somehow?

Comment: Parameter-sniffing doesn't have anything to do with picking up the plans for other statements it has to do with the fact that the same query with different parameters should get different plans for best performance.  However, once parametrized, queries will get stuck or frozen on one plan that is bad for most (or even all) parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the information, we do NOT have Forced Parameterization turn on (I confirmed it is off for the Server and this database). As for different parameters, nope... same exact query was the ONLY values sent ever to this server.  In fact, given the nature of the bug, the only values that could have changed are the strings in the middle of the (evil, ICK!!) LIKE '%' + @parameter + '%' clauses.

It's something strange in the server, near as I can tell.  Seems to be behaving since being rebooted.

Comment: If the same query, with the same values produces different execution plans depending on whether it is parametrized or not, that's parameter-sniffing because that's the definition of parameter-sniffing.

Comment: What I have not figured out is why it is using sp_executesql and parametrizing it so much, because I didn't think that simple parametrization would go that far.

Comment: When reproducing performance issues from captured queries in SQL Profiler ensure that you also include all the `SET` options. Something as simple as a different `SET ARITHABORT` is different enough to not correctly reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this situation today and the fix that solved my problem is to use `WITH (NOLOCK)` while doing a select on tables:

Eg: If your stored proc has T-SQL that looks like below:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Employee]
```

Change it to

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Employee] WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: that can certainly eliminate lock contentions... but could yield stale (bad) data.

Answer (score 1):

I've had off-hours jobs fubar my indexes before and I've gotten the same result as you describe.  sp_recompile can recompile a sproc... or, if that doesn't work, the sp_recompile can be run on the table and all sprocs that act on that table will be recompiled -- works for me every time.

Comment: No stored procs in the game. Statistics updated, ALL indexes rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem before as well.  Sounds like your indexes are out of whack.  To get the same behavior in SSMS, add this before the script

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF
```

Does it timeout as well?  If so, it's your indexing and statistics

Comment: Tried that, didn't change anything. The connection, database and server defaults are ARITHABORT ON. Trace show same connection options for both connections:
-- network protocol: TCP/IP
set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort on
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7
set transaction isolation level read committed

Comment: By didn't change anything, I mean that I added that to the SSMS and it still finish in sub-second time.

Comment: Having the same problem and `SET ARITHABORT OFF` also causes SSMS to time out.  So if it's indexing/statistics, how do we resolve or rebuild them?

Comment: So I rebuilt the indexes (http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/rebuilding_indexes_p1.aspx) and the problem went away.  Looks like we need a maintenance plan (http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/Standards/Rules/RulesToBetterSQLServerDatabases.aspx#MaintenancePlan) or something similar to prevent this.  Any idea why it occurs in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely index-related. Had a similar issue with .Net app vs SSMS (specifically on a proc using a temp table w/ < 100 rows). We added a clustered index on the table and it flew from .Net thereafter.

Comment: All tables have all the indexes (of the right kind) you could ever wish for.. the plan shows nothing but happy-path plan elements.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this behavior before and it can be a big problem with o/r mappers that use sp_executesql. If you examine the execution plans you'll likely find that the sp_executesql query is not making good use of indexes. I spent a fair amount of time trying to find a fix or explanation for this behavior but never got anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your .Net programs pass the variables as **NVARCHAR**, not as **VARCHAR**. Your indexes are on VARCHAR columns I assume (judging from your script), and a condition like `ascii_column = @unicodeVariable` is actually not SARG-able. The plan has to generate a scan in this case, where in SSMS would generate a seek because the variable is the right type.

Make sure you pass all your string as VARCHAR parameters, or modify your query to explicitly cast the variables, like this:

```
SELECT dv.ID
FROM dbo.DictionaryValue AS dv
WHERE dv.Word LIKE '%' + CAST(@FieldCheckValue5 AS VARCHAR(128)) + '%'
```

Comment: No, sorry. Read the question again... I show the .Net trace's call and it IS passing in exactly the correct datatypes. Our access layer gets that right.